# overlapping html form

Tags: html, css

I want to disable a form by showing a div on top of a TD cell, but I can't find the way to set proper width and height my try was `width:100%; height:100%;` but this overlaps more than the TD surface

```
<table><tr><td>the data:<td>
  <div style="position:absolute;background-color:#cccccc;opacity:0.70;">not alowed</div>
  <form method="post" action="aaaa.htm">
    <input type=text><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There are no closing TD or TR tags.

Comment: that isnt a good way to disable a form.

Comment: @Daniel: overlaping with a div (or something) is what paypal do on their login, I want to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is nothing wrong with this approach, and it has the same efficiency as `disabled="disabled"`:

- both ways the inputs' values can be changed
- both ways the values will be submitted
- both ways prevent the user to click on the field

**Suggestion**: use the overlay with `disabled="disabled"` - looks much better and the fields could not be focused with the `TAB` button.

So, back to the question - the overlay div could not be re-sized to take the `<form>`'s width and height without using javascript.

This is my **[jsFiddle solution example with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/jRDpn/1/)** what it basically does is getting the form and appending a `<div>` inside with the same width and height. And disables all `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements inside the form

Answer (score 0):

Better to just remove the `div` and do something like this

`<input type=text disabled="disabled" value="Not Allowed">`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GxNLY/

Comment: What's the point of disabling an input element without disabling the submit button?

Comment: That's a good point @RobW.  I was simply following the OP's code.

Comment: I have reduced the example shown here, I prefer to overlap something over the full form